# Как скопировать текст из PuTTY и вставить его в текстовый редактор в Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

Как скопировать текст из PuTTY (терминала) и вставить его в любой текстовый редактор в Linux?

Подразумевается, что терминал и текстовый редактор запущены на одной и той же машине.

Comment: У Вас PuTTY на винде на одной машине, а убунта на другой?

Comment: нет, путти запускается на убунту, мне нужно скопировать текст из окна путти, и например процитировать его в этом комментарии на stackoverflow.    http://rghost.net/88bMz5JgC/image.png

Comment: Насколько помню, при выделении мышкой selection (выделенный текст) помещается в copy/paste буфер и его можно вставить в любое окно  (которое позволяет это делать).

Comment: Просто ради любопытства спрошу. А зачем Вам PuTTY на линуксе?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+C && Ctrl+Shift+V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> в терминале работает как SIGINT (сигнал прерывания текущей операции), для копирования в буфер обмена вместо него используется сочетание <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (а для вставки, соответственно, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

Кроме того, в Linux-системах с графическим интерфейсом есть и другой способ работать с буфером обмена: выделите текст мышью, чтобы скопировать, и кликните средней кнопкой мыши, чтобы вставить. При этом "классический" буфер (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) и "мышиный" могут использоваться параллельно, в один и тот же момент времени содержа в себе разный текст.

Comment: Отличный ответ, наверняка для многих очень полезный. Вот, например, я всю жизнь работал в \*nix, а о Ctrl-Shft-C/Ctrl-Shft-V и не знал... --  сейчас попробовал в своем `xfce4-terminal` (вот прямо эта вставка из вывода `ps`) -- **работает!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Методом тыка выяснилось, что только после того как текст скопирован и вставлен в окне putty, содержание буфера putty передается в буфер ubuntu. Далее текст можно копировать в любой редактор ubuntu.